# SQL Get minimum hour from multiple datetimes registers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need display INFO column, having the minimum hour for each date in REGISTRATION column, one for LOG

```
Log CAT   INFO       REGISTRATION
10  1   551203  2018-06-04 08:47:54.000
10  1   551549  2018-06-05 08:59:02.000
579 1   551675  2018-06-05 10:13:36.000
579 1   553681  2018-06-05 11:31:44.000
579 1   551707  2018-06-05 12:57:33.000
579 1   551364  2018-06-04 10:16:04.000
579 1   551378  2018-06-04 10:39:01.000
579 1   551379  2018-06-04 10:40:22.000
579 1   551406  2018-06-04 15:47:52.000
580 1   550922  2018-06-04 11:21:01.000
580 1   551001  2018-06-04 12:43:22.000
580 1   553321  2018-06-04 15:37:52.000
```

exactly this, where each INFO are the minimum hour of each date, of each LOG

```
INFO
551203       -->(2018-06-04 08:47:54.000)        
551675       -->(2018-06-05 10:13:36.000)   
551364       -->(2018-06-04 10:16:04.000)   
550922       -->(2018-06-04 11:21:01.000)
```

thanks!!

Comment: I'm having difficulty figuring out how you got the results you laid out there. I'm confused as to where the "hour" part comes in. If you group by `log` and the hour of the registration date, I wind up with 8 rows. If I group by `log` and just the date component, I end up with 5 rows.

Comment: Sorry. I need display INFO whit the minimun datetime REGISTRATION for each LOG and each DAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that info values appear in increasing order then I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select min(info) as info, min(registration) as registration
from log
group by log, cast(registration as date);
```

Or just use `row_number()` to avoid making that assumption:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over 
            (partition by log, cast(registration as date) order by registration) as rn
    from log
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry. No, Info is not increasing. Its reandom

Comment: Ok @Ljgazzano, see the second query then.